# Failed to find stack for package [joy] (installing for Nao or PR2 robot)

Tags: ros, pr2, joy, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am a newbie here. I got an error message when trying to install ros package for nao robot. I am planning to install ros for pr 2 and nao. I have successfully configured my environment for pr 2.

```
...[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find stack for package [joy]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [joy]:Cannot locate installation of package joy: [rospack] couldn't find package [joy]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/anshar/ros_workspace:/home/anshar/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
......
```

Thank you

Cheers,

ryann2k1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33246/failed-to-find-stack-for-package-%5Bjoy%5D-(installing-for-nao-or-pr2-robot)/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please be more specific. What exactly are you installing, and where? The error is not specific to either the PR2 or Nao robot. What command causes this error?

Looking at "Failed to find stack for package [joy]", it seems like you don't have the "joy" package installed. By looking at its [wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/joy), you can infer that it's in the "joystick_drivers" stack. You need to install that stack, either from source or with the debian package ros-electric-joystick-drivers.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0